# How can one position navigation bar item in Swift?

Tags: swift, uikit, navigationbar

I have a navigation bar that currently only has a back button. I am trying to add an image button on the right side of the navigation bar but the image I am using is larger than the navigation bar and ends up covering the back button and gets positioned strangely.

This is the code:

```
let mapBtn = UIButton(type: .system)
mapBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "map-1"), for: .normal)
mapBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 5,height: 5)

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: mapBtn)
```

This is an image of what is happening:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpuGp.jpg

Is there anyway to add a constraint to the mapBtn to make it stick to the right side as it should be?

Comment: What's the size of your image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to resize your image**

```
   func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    let size = image.size

    let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / image.size.width
    let heightRatio = targetSize.height / image.size.height

    // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
    var newSize: CGSize
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio,  height: size.height * widthRatio)
    }

    // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

    // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    if let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(){
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage

    }else{
        return nil
    }
}
 let mapBtn = UIButton(type: .system)
 let img = UIImage(named: "map-1")
 let resizedImage = resizeImage(image: img, targetSize:  CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0) 
 mapBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 5,height: 5)
 mapBtn.setImage(resizedImage, for: .normal)
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: mapBtn)
```

Comment: @LudovicoVerniani Welcome

Answer (score 0):

set this.

```
mapBtn.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```